# Deploying Ibm Cloud Functions with multiple actions at once using manifest.yml having thirdparty dependecies

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I am having a set of three APIs with different paths using a third party npm dependency which I am trying to deploy on IBM Cloud functions using the openwhisk manifest.yml file declaring the actions and apis.
However, the third party npm modules don't get installed on the cloud functions servers.
I am aware that I can create zip files and deploy each zip for respective actions individually but I intend to deploy them collectively as they are part of the same package.
Please guide me on how to go about achieving this.

```
packages:
 stocks_package:
  version: 1.0
  license: Apache-2.0
  actions:
   test:
    function: index.js
    web-export: true
   test2:
    function: index.js
    web-export: true
  apis:
   stocks-me:
    base:
      test:
        test:
          method: GET
          response: http
      test2:
        test2:
          method: GET
          response: http
```

Comment: Add more details, e.g., your manifest file. Each action stands on its own and is mapped to a runtime container.

Comment: I updated the manifest.yml here. Yes, and I need those runtime containers to contain my thirdparty npm dependency. How can it be done?

Comment: Just asking, are you aware of https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-prep? It describes how to pack the code.

Comment: Yes, I am. I've gone through it multiple times but couldn't find anything relevant to my ask. As I said, I am aware of zipping and updating an action but I want to deploy for multiple actions at once each having external npm dependencies. Can you please help with that?